# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to set a model object on a component without a model! Either pass an IModel to the constructor or

Tags: java, spring-mvc, wicket-8

Getting below error on IndicatingAjaxButton click in wicket 8.x version.

> ERROR | Exception occured:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to set a model object on a component without a model! Either pass an IModel to the constructor or use #setDefaultModel(new SomeModel(object)). Component: form:savedQuery
> at org.apache.wicket.Component.setDefaultModelObject(Component.java:2999)
> at org.apache.wicket.IGenericComponent.setModelObject(IGenericComponent.java:81)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.updateModel(FormComponent.java:1100)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$FormModelUpdateVisitor.component(Form.java:223)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$FormModelUpdateVisitor.component(Form.java:193)
> at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:274)
> at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:262)
> at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrder(Visits.java:245)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.visitComponentsPostOrder(FormComponent.java:426)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.internalUpdateFormComponentModels(Form.java:1873)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.updateFormComponentModels(Form.java:1838)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:990)
> at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:825)
> at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:176)
> at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:127)
> at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:598)
> at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.internalInvoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:306)
> at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:280)
> at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerRequestHandler.java:222)
> at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.respond(ListenerRequestHandler.java:208)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:914)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:282)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
> at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:275)
> at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:206)
> at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:299)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:204)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
> at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
final DropDownChoice<String> listSites = (DropDownChoice<String>) new DropDownChoice<String>("savedQueries", new PropertyModel<String>(TestPage.this.getModel(), "selectedValue"), savedQueries).add(new FormComponentUpdatingBehavior() {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void onUpdate() {
    // Update logic
}


    protected void onError(RuntimeException ex) {
        super.onError(ex);
    }
});
    
listSites.setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(listSites); 


            
TextField savedQuery = new TextField<>("savedQuery"); // CHECK LATER 
savedQuery.setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(savedQuery);

final IndicatingAjaxButton deleteMcb = new IndicatingAjaxButton("delete") {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        String message=null;
        List<String> savedQueries = null;
        try{
            //on submit process logic
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
     
        listSites.setChoices(savedQueries);
        listSites.setModelObject(null);
        target.add(listSites);
        savedQuery.setModelObject(null);
        target.add(savedQuery);
        target.add(feedback);
        error(message);
    }
    
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this exception after adding this below line of code for TextField object.

```
savedQuery.setDefaultModel(Model.of(queryName));
```

queryName is a String value parameter here.